# Python-Selenium test script not working

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am trying to automation some action on a website using Python and Selenium, this is the sample code I am trying to run, [from the Mozilla website for running the Firefox webdriver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver#Python_2)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
caps["marionette"] = True
caps["binary"] = "/usr/bin/firefox-aurora"

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

When running this code, the Firefox instance opens normally, and I can even use the instance as if I just opened Firefox normally, but the code 'stops' executing at the `driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)` line, I tried debugging the code with no luck, the whole execution seems to just stop at this line, and nothing after it is reached!

I am running `Python3.5`, `Selenium version 2.53.6`, I have the 'Wires' executable at the `/usr/local/bin` which is in the environment's PATH, I also have `Firefox Aurora version 49.0a2` running on ArchLinux.

Thanks in advance.

[Update:]
I managed to get it to work after all using Firefox 46 (the normal version).

Comment: Could you try with Firefox 46?

Comment: @alecxe so I tried downgrading Firefox, apparently some dependeny of it is removed (and pacman didn't retrieve it) and Firefox 46 wouldn't work. I know that Firefox 47 isn't supported and that's why I used Firefox DevEdition (Aurora) which the Mozilla site said it is supported.

Comment: I managed to downgrade Firefox after all !! It now works using Firefox 46, although it still doesn't work on the Developer Edition, but it's okay it'll do what I want !! Thanks @alecxe :D